# Android GCM Push Notifications are not working on some devices

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm facing a strange issue. I recently got my app updated and GCM Push Notification stopped working on some models of phones. Samsung S8 plus is one of such models. It works on other phones. I've done a bit of search but nothing seems to be working. I've followed the instructions from https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-your-push-notifications-never-see-the-light-of-day-3fa297520793 which doesn't work.

On device notification settings are set for app and also it works for other apps.

Does anyone know what else I can try to fix this issue?

Can this issue be in the code itself or can it be fixed in the code?

Comment: What does entering the code `*#*#426#*#*` in the phone app give? (It should open a Google Play Services / GCM debug app.)